# TinyMCE data manipulation

Tags: php, html, tinymce, html-parsing, html-to-pdf

Hi i got some html string and i want to make changes on it and print it.
In order to make simple changes like adding text into it, i could insert my html inside tinyMCE and makes changes and save it as string. However i have some php values and i have to insert it in html before i save it and print that html. How can i do it?

I could do html changes and save it as a string but there is some issues to print it out and make changes in that string.

For example,

I have textbox and i want to insert some values in it with php like

```
 <input type='text' value='<?php echo $phpvariable ?>'>
```

or i have image inside tinymce and i want to add location for that image. Eg;

```
<img id='specificimage' src=''> to <img id='specificimage src='<?php echo $imagepath ?>'>
```

and here is my template code for it

```
<?php
 $allowedTags='<p><strong><em><u><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><img>';
 $allowedTags.='<li><ol><ul><span><div><br><ins><del>';  
// Should use some proper HTML filtering here.
  if($_POST['elm1']!='') {
    $sHeader = '<h1>Ah, content is king.</h1>';
    $sContent = strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['elm1']),$allowedTags);
} else {
    $sHeader = '<h1>Nothing submitted yet</h1>';
    $sContent = '<p>Start typing...</p>';
    $sContent.= '<p><img width="107" height="108" border="0" src="/mediawiki/images/badge.png"';
    $sContent.= 'alt="TinyMCE button"/>This rover has crossed over</p>';
  }
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>My test editor - with tinyMCE and PHP</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  tinyMCE.init({
    theme : "advanced",
    mode: "exact",
    elements : "elm1",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,separator,"
    + "justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,formatselect,"
    + "bullist,numlist,outdent,indent",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "link,unlink,anchor,image,separator,"
    +"undo,redo,cleanup,code,separator,sub,sup,charmap",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    height:"350px",
    width:"600px"
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <?php echo $sHeader;?>
 <h2>Sample using TinyMCE and PHP</h2>
 <form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>">
  <textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80"><?php echo $sContent;?></textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" />
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<input type='textbox' value='<?php echo $phpvariable ?>'>` can't you just add a name attribute to it and use a variable against a POST array? Unsure if that's the goal here.

Comment: btw, `type='textbox'` isn't a valid type. You either meant to use `type='text'` or a `<textarea>`.

Comment: then you have `<img id='specificimage' url=''>` the syntax is `img src` and not `img url`.

Comment: Furkan L It looks like you me and @Fred-ii- have no idea what you are doing or asking. Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: well @RiggsFolly I'm outta here Smokey. See you on the flipside ;-)

Comment: Im gonna try to explain it then. These input and img src are just example that im trying to do. I got rich text box(TinyMCE) and i add some html string to show some content in it. Firstly i have to change that string. That string include some html content also include textbox and images. I have values for them that are $textboxvalue and $imagepathurl. After i change these values in that string which is also in TinyMCE(Rich Text Box) , i should print that string(html) with using any kind of library. That is a goal =)